# CouchDB document replication(updating specific attributes of a document)

Tags: couchdb

I have an issue of replication and I need your help in it.In couchDb replication,I want to replicate in such a way that during Couchdb replication I want to reset/update some specific attributes of a a document for some purpose and then these edited documents should be saved in replicated db without effecting the original ones.For example:
A document named Student with attributes id,name,class etc.
And I want to replicate this document in the way that its name and class should be reset/updated.
Will you please tell me how can I achieve it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update docs during the replication.

But you can exclude docs from being replicated with the help of a CouchDB filter (e.g. preventing all docs with a revision higher then 1 from being replicated).

If you want to have multiple versions of the same dataset (e.g. to have dataset revisions) - i use the term "dataset" instead of "doc" to clearly express that not the internal CouchDB doc revision handling is involved - you have to store them as separated docs that have all a unique id and a reference property like `original: "UUID_of_the_original"`.

**you can't use the CouchDB doc revision handling for that purpose (thats what many people think when they see the `_rev` property in the docs)**

Comment: Ok.Is there any alternative way to do that.?

Comment: I thought you got an alternative way described in my answer. Simple don't update the originals - create new docs with a reference to the original.